# Split curl method into 3x parts

Tags: php, curl, php-5.3

Is it possible to split `curl` in 3 parts?

For example, I have the following code:

```
$headers = array(
    "Content-Type:application/json",
    "Authorization:key=" . self::ANDROID_AUTH_KEY
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
//result sample {"multicast_id":6375780939476727795,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1390531659626943%6cd617fcf9fd7ecd"}]}
//http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html // refer error code
curl_close($ch);
```

In this case, I would like to have a method, for example : `connect()` that will do `curl_init()` once, after that I want to have a method `send()` that will call `curl_exec()` which then posts parameters 10x times, and after that `disconnect()` that will do `curl_close()` that will be called once.

Is this something which is possible?

Please help me.

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI can you help me please ?

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI Try and be slightly more constructive when commenting on users questions. An example of this would be, It's OOP not Object Oriented Programming*s*

Comment: Your question is way too general, and I'm afraid SO isn't (or shouldn't be) a code writing service. You already have most of what you need. Now you should read on functions (http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) and start from there to deconstruct your code in smaller pieces. OOP (http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.php) is a bit more advanced, and since you are asking this I'd advise to begin with something more basic. Regards.